# Почему css in (дюйм) не соответсвует реальному?

Tags: css

День добрый, вот смотрите:

```css
div {
  width: 1in;
  height: 1in;
  background: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Блок имеет размеры 1x1 дюйм, но я прикладываю к экрану линейку и вижу, что его реальные размеры 1.2...см. Почему? Дюймом же считаются 2.54см.

Comment: Линейка у вас не той системы :) а если серьезно, то на моем мониторе развер вполне себе соответствует одному дюйму. монитор 23.6

Comment: Сегодня на нескольких планшетах/телефонах проверял, везде мельче, чем 2.54.

Comment: что еще в CSS прописано? вот если взять сейчас тот квадрат что в вопросе, он нормального размера у вас?

Comment: @Константин, посмотрите эту статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/121964/

Comment: DPI устройства неверно определяется. И чую, придется с этим мирится. Если запустить на моем мониторе - все ОК, передвинуть открытое окно на второй монитор и уже больше дюйма.

Comment: @Vitalts разные мониторы?

Comment: Да, с разными диагоналями. При одной резолюции пиксель большего будет больших размеров реальной линейки.

Comment: @Vitalts, Спасибо, теперь ясно. Я именно для определения DPI и намеревался использовать этот блок. Определяет на всех моих устройствах 96dpi (в реальности цифры совсем иные), как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от диагонали монитора и его разрешения. Даже на одном мониторе при разных разрешениях размеры разные будут. На вскидку в поиске Яндекса - http://www.realcoding.net/article/view/482